# Visual Studio Code Without intellisense in Angular Project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am working with an Angular project but when I add control labels to me the intellisense is not shown

instead of this

[image: intellisense]

I see this

[image: no intelllisense]

I have these extensions installed

[image: extensions]

I don't know which one else I can miss

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please restart vs code, this because the vs code caches these settings.

Comment: Sorry I have restarted it 10 times before write this post and the problem remains. Thanks